# The enveloping $C^*$ algebra of $C^k[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

We know that $C^k[0,1]$ is an abelian $*$-Banach algebra, but it is not a $C^*$ algebra in general unless $k=0$.

**I wonder what's the enveloping $C^*$ algebra of $C^k[0,1]$?** I guess it might be $C[0,1]$. However, I am not able to prove it right now.

What I can show right now is that the maximal ideal space of $C^k[0,1]$ is $[0,1]$, In another word, all the $1$ dimensional $*$-representation are in this form.

In order to find the enveloping $C^*$ algebra, **I think we need to find all the $*$-representation instead of those in only $1$ dimension.** However, I have no idea how to do this.

Any help will be truly grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $f\in C^k=:A$ is invertible if and only if $f$ does not vanish on $[0,1].$ Hence $\sigma_A(f)=f([0,1]).$
For any $*$-representation $\pi: A\to B(\mathcal{H})$ and $f\in A,$ the operator $\pi(f)$  is normal. Therefore $$\|\pi(f)\|=\max\{|z|\in \mathbb{C}\,:\,z\in \sigma(\pi(f))\}$$
In other words the norm is equal to the spectral radius. As $\pi$ is a homomorphism ( $\pi(1)=I$) we have $$\sigma(\pi(f))\subset \sigma_A(f)=f([0,1])$$
Therefore
$$\|\pi(f)\|\le \max_{0\le x\le 1}|f(x)|=\|f\|_\infty$$
For every $t\in [0,1]$ we have the one-dimensional representation $\pi_t(f)=f(t).$ Therefore
$$\sup_{0\le t\le 1}\|\pi_t(f)\|=\|f\|_\infty$$
Summarizing the norm of $f$ in the $C^*$-enveloping algebra of $C^k[0,1]$ is equal $\|f\|_\infty.$ Therefore this algebra is $*$-isometrically isomorphic to $C[0,1].$

**Remark** Another way is to use the fact that the norm on the enveloping algebra can be determined by irreducible representations of $A,$ i.e. one-dimensional in the commutative case.

Comment: The norm in $C^k$ is different from the norm in $C$, it should be defined here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291235/cn0-1-is-not-a-c-algebra

Comment: If not so,  we assume that$C^k$ equipped with the norm $||\cdot||_{\infty}$, then it may not be a Banach space. Despite that, I think this proof still works.                                                          But how do we prove the remark you pointed out at last? I think this proof you give here is strongly related to the structure of continuous functions. Would you like to give me any reference for the general property you pointed out?

Comment: To be more specific, I think the equation $\sigma_A(f)=f([0,1])$ is trivial here, but we can't get a similar result if we get rid of the structure of continuous functions.

Comment: If the norm is different then my answer useless and I will delete it. Concerning your last question if $f\in C^k$ and $f$ does not vanish then $f$ is invertible in $C^k.$ So the spectra in $C[0,1]$ and $C^k[0,1]$ coincide.

Comment: Although the norm is different, I think your proof still works for this special case. The key point is to realize that the spectra of $f$ in $C^k[0,1]$ is $f([0,1])$. I am not sure if your remark is true in general.

Comment: I have just re-edited the answer. This time I do not use the norm whatsover.

Comment: I have removed the remark, as it became irrelevant.